# jquery ui datepicker - altfield as a div rather than input

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the altfield and altformat options on the jquery ui datepicker to display a friendly date to the user, while having the date formatted for the database in a hidden field. The only thing is, I don't want the date shown to the user in an input box (visually it suggests they can type in it), I just want it shown as text. I know I could style an input box so it doesn't look like it is one, but I'd rather just use a div and update the text. However, it only seems to work with an input field, if you set it to a div id, it does nothing.

Has anyone overcome this issue?

Comment: I wanted to suggest, that you just turn the field disabled, but on jquery ui datepicker site that stopped script from working. Perhaps you can use disabled field and still catch click events on it, open datepicker and update its value?

Hack its code and add ability to use disabled inputs :P

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can get it to work with a disabled input field, but from a usability point of view - I don't want it to be an input field at all because I don't want it to give the signal that users _could_ type something into it, even if they can't!

Comment: dude, if you css it right, then average computer user wont even understand its input field. I use my gf for dumbuser tests, even through she has somewhat decent computer skills. all those tests have shown me that if something does not look like it usually does, then it probably aint it. Meaning if your input looks nothing like input and if you cant change its contents when you edit it, then it probably is not input. User just accepts the fact that he cant do anything there.Give disabled input same bg as content area, replace borders or remove borders at all. And there you go.

Answer (score 11):

I've gotten it to display in a div using this in the onSelect:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
//formatDate Requires a new date object to work
      var myDate = new Date(dateText);

//Set a new var with different format to use
      var newFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate("DD, d MM, yy", myDate);
//Choose the div you want to replace
      $("#yourselctorhere").html(newFormat);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to make the input of type=hidden then select the value and assign it to the text of your div

```
$("myPicker").datepicker({
altField: "#altInput",
```

.

```
var hiddenDate = $("[name='altInput']").attr('value');
$("#myDate").text(hiddenDate);}
});
```

.

```
<input id = "altInput" type = "hidden"/>
<div id = "myDate"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Css :P

```
.div,.div:focus{
    display:block;
    background:#fff;
    border:0px;
    color:#333
}
<input type="text" class="div" readonly id="altInput" />
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way i found is to change this in the **jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.js** file

first search for **_updateAlternative** function and change this line:

```
$(altField).each(function() { $(this).val(dateStr); });
```

for example i have changed to this :

```
$(altField).each(function() { $(this).val(dateStr); $(this).text(dateStr); });
```

now you can put the alternative text in any element you want.
i Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
// altField: '#dp-date',
onSelect: function(dateText) {
    $('#dp-date').html(dateText);
},
```